# can i add something else in the if statement to check for the values two cells in the row in order to be delete?

Tags: vba, excel

it is possible for me to write in the code to check that

```
If Range("A" & i).Value Like "cell is not blank" & Range("M" & i).Value Like "Complete" Then
```

in order to delete just that row because as of right now it delete all my rows that are complete but i also want those rows to have something in cell A in order to be delete.

```
Dim UsdRws As Long

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

UsdRws = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = UsdRws To 2 Step -1

If Range("M" & i).Value Like "Complete" Then

Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Complete").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Rows(i).Delete

End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried it?  NB: the logical operator is `AND` not `&` (which is the string concatenation operator).

Comment: `Range("A" & i).Value<>"" And`

Comment: Thank You, the program works perfectly